# Let $f(x)=x\cos(x)$, Which of following is true?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> 1. Let $f(x) = x\cos x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. Then 
>      $\quad$(A) There is a sequence $x_n\to -\infty$ such that $f(x_n)\to 0$.
>      $\quad$(B) There is a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $f(x_n)\to\infty.$
>      $\quad$(C) There is a sequence $x_n \to\infty$ such that $f(x_n)\to-\infty$.
>      $\quad$(D) $f$ is a uniformly continuous function.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TInJk.png)

If I take sequence $-n$, first option is true. What about other options?

Thanks.

Comment: $(A)$ is true. Let $x_n=\pi/2-n\pi$. Your example $x_n=-n$ is wrong: you're right that $x_n\stackrel{n\to \infty}\to -\infty$, but $f(x_n)=-n\cos(-n)\not\stackrel{n\to \infty}\to 0$ (we have $|-n\cos (-n)|\stackrel{n\to \infty}\to \infty$).

Comment: Hint: What about drawing the graph of the function?

Comment: Every option except the last is true

Comment: @Omnomnomnom how

Comment: (B) and (C) are nothing different from (A), just choose $x$ appropriately so that $\cos(x)=\pm 1$ in each case. For (D) for given $\varepsilon>0$ required $\delta$ for continuity decreases at each $x$ intercepts for $x>0$, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) is true , if you pick $x_n = \pi/2 - n\pi$ you get $f(X)=0$ for every $x$ real. B) is true, if you pick $x_n = 2n\pi$ $f$ goes to $+\infty$ since $cos=1$. $C)$ is true, if you pick $x_n = (2n + 1)\pi$ $f$ goes to $-\infty$ since $cos = -1$. D) is false cause $f'(X) = cosX - XsinX \simeq -X$ for the right choise of $X$ becoming bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 2):

If you graph the function you will see that the function wiggles into a bow-tie shape. So you can pick sequences going to in either direction ( $x_n \rightarrow _-^+ \infty$) such that $ f(x_n)$ will go to  $_-^+ \infty$ or 0.